# pandas Series: Remove and replace NaNs with interpolated data point

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation, series

I have a pandas Series and I have currently just resampled it using

```
signal = pd.Series(thick, index = pd.TimedeltaIndex(time_list_thick,unit = 's'))
resampled_signal = signal.resample('1S').mean()
```

However, my resampled data contains NaNs which I would like to remove:

```
00:00:00.415290    451.369402
00:00:01.415290           NaN
00:00:02.415290    451.358724
00:00:03.415290    451.356055
00:00:04.415290    451.350716
00:00:05.415290    451.340039
00:00:06.415290           NaN
00:00:07.415290    451.332031
00:00:08.415290    451.326692
00:00:09.415290    451.318684
00:00:10.415290    451.310675
00:00:11.415290           NaN
00:00:12.415290    451.302667
00:00:13.415290    451.291990
00:00:14.415290           NaN
00:00:15.415290    451.286651
00:00:16.415290    451.278643
00:00:17.415290    451.274639
00:00:18.415290    451.265296
00:00:19.415290           NaN
00:00:20.415290    451.255953
00:00:21.415290           NaN
00:00:22.415290    451.243941
00:00:23.415290           NaN
00:00:24.415290    451.234598
00:00:25.415290           NaN
00:00:26.415290    451.225255
00:00:27.415290    451.219916
00:00:28.415290    451.211908
00:00:29.415290    451.201231
```

What I would like to do is replace these NaNs with an interpolated point whos value lies in between the nearest finite data points (for example: line 2 in my data would be around 451.364..). Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `df.interpolate()` to perform this operation. Additionally, the `time` method can be used in order to take time-based index into account.

As follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np


todays_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
index = pd.date_range(todays_date, periods=10, freq='D')
A = np.random.rand(10)
A[1::4] = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': A }, index=index)
df['A'] = df['A'].interpolate(method='time')
```

Before:

```
                   A
2021-08-03  0.360953
2021-08-04       NaN
2021-08-05  0.801508
2021-08-06  0.927827
2021-08-07  0.532153
2021-08-08       NaN
2021-08-09  0.897129
2021-08-10  0.713843
2021-08-11  0.709481
2021-08-12       NaN
```

After:

```
                   A
2021-08-03  0.360953
2021-08-04  0.581230
2021-08-05  0.801508
2021-08-06  0.927827
2021-08-07  0.532153
2021-08-08  0.714641
2021-08-09  0.897129
2021-08-10  0.713843
2021-08-11  0.709481
2021-08-12  0.709481
```